# How to break up the "main class" structure for PHP export?

Tags: php, haxe

This is my current project.hxml:

```
-cp Source
-main Login
-php Export/Server
-v
```

What this does is take one of the classes (Login.hx) and use it as the main class for the whole PHP server.
This isn't very useful for PHP, though, as PHP does not really support the notion of a "main" class, instead you'd need a .php script for each function you want to call on the server from the web, working mostly independently from each other.

The biggest problem here is obviously the "main" class as haxe outputs everything into the specified folder, but renames the Login.hx to index.php.
However, I don't want it to become index.php.
What I want is a login.php, logout.php, morestuff.php, basically all of my haxe classes to become callable php scripts, to be able to call them like this:

```
/appname/login  
/appname/logout
/appname/morestuff  
etc.
```

The only ways to achieve this I could think of right now are not-so-nice workarounds.

1. Create a much bigger project.hxml file, outputting each class into its own folder (so *Export/Server/Login, Export/Server/Logout*, etc.) using *--next*. That would work, but would also blow up the size as all the .php files haxe outputs (Std, etc.) would be duplicate within these folders.
2. Have an actual Main class that uses parameters to "forward" the different calls to the actual classes. So basically the calls would become */appname/Main?function=login, /appname/Main?function=logout*, etc.
   This would be more acceptable, but still feels kinda cumbersome.
3. I'm not a PHP expert, but there is probably a way to do this doing some configurations in PHP internals. I'd rather not.

Surely, there must be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrestled with this same issue you are having and this was the best I could do.
You can change the filename of the php entry script in the hxml file or command-line option using:

```
--php-front newfilename.php
```

You might also find it useful to change where the lib directory is located:

```
--php-lib ../lib
```

So the full settings in the hxml file (to generate multiple php entry points) might look like so:

```
-cp src
-main Main
--php-front joomlahaxe.php
-php bin/com_joomlahaxe/site
-debug

--next
-cp src
-main JoomlahaxeViewJoomlahaxe
--php-front view.html.php   
--php-lib ../../lib
-php bin/com_joomlahaxe/site/views/joomlahaxe
```

Comment: Okay, so basically like my first workaround, but with better hxml magic. Doesn't sound too bad, just too bad having --next in a script messes with autocompletion so bad. Thankfully, I DO know a workaround for that, too ;)

Comment: I'll accept this, should a less workaround-like answer not pop up in a few days.

Comment: I found out about a significant problem with this: Each --next target will overwrite the "lib" folder of the previous target.  If the target B, for example, does not use a function that a previous script A uses, it will not appear in the resulting lib folder, thus breaking the script A. So that does require the weird workaround of each php-class having to use every needed Lib-function or risk that the function disappears in the end result. Ugh!

Comment: Basically, the dead code elimination of target B (potentially) destroys target A if both output to the same folder.